# I need to change background color of v-tab selected - VUETIFY

Tags: vuetify.js

I have this code:

```
<v-tabs color="#949494" hide-slider class="ml-5 mt-4">
        <v-tab v-for="aba in abas" :key="aba.ordem" class="mr-1" exact exact-active-class="active" :to="construirRota(aba)">
            {{ aba.titulo }}
        </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

and i get this result:
[thisResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfzji.png)

but i need to change background color of only selected tab and also dont change text color of my selected tab , how can i do this ?

Comment: Then use background-color

Comment: if i set the background-color of my v-tab all <v-tab> will have same color, not only selected tab

Comment: Use background-color for the child element. In your case it is v-tab not v-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want to change the backgroundcolor its:

```
background-color: #949494
```

```
color: #949494
```

changes the font color

if you want to do it with inline css as it is in your example it would be:

```
style="background-color: #949494"
```

If you want the activated v-tab, you have to address the v-tab with the :active selector.
However, this is not possible via inline css. So you need a css file in which you insert the following code:

```
v-tab:active {
    background-color: #949494
}
```

Comment: i just want to change background-color when my tab is selected, if i do this in my v-tab all <v-tab> will have the same background color...

Comment: I've edited my answer, you have to use the :active selector to access your activated element

Comment: when i click on my tab the new background color stay for a few moments and the older one turn back

Comment: the color stays as long your element is active. So the color changes back when it is no longer active